# remove all domain except one defined domain in php string

Tags: php

I want to remove all the domain names from a string excet example.com from a php string. can anyone please write the regular expression in doing it.

```
preg_replace("/!http://example.com[^>]+\>/i", "", $string);
```

but it is not working. can anyone please in this regards.

Regards,

Comment: use a negative lookahead.

Comment: @Stony How does that answer make an exception for one doain?

Comment: @Barmar its an Regex to remove the domain name so whats the problem? ;) "I wan't to remove ALLLLL domain names from a string" so here are on Stackoverflow are enough answers to solve that problem.

Comment: @Stony **except example.com**

Comment: The OP should combine the regexp in the second question with the exception handler in the first question.

Comment: @Bamar: I haven't said that its the complete correct answer. When you try to programming something you should think about the problem and try to find a solution with a hint to learn something or what do you think? You are right the solution is to combine the First Answer and exclude the domain you need. But its much easier to filter the string with strpos first and check if your domain you want to keep is in your string and otherwise use the regex. When your regex is to complicated its a problem to change them after a few weeks.

Comment: Can anyone please write the sample code , as i am new to regular expression. actually i am gathering the html source and saving it into a string. i want to remove all the urls except my url that contains my domain name.